# trying to get proberty data of non object AND trying to get property version of non object issue in php

Tags: php, json

Sometimes i am getting the error from the following line

**Notice: trying to get property data of non object**

**Notice: trying to get property version of non object**

```
$json = json_decode($url);  
    if($json->data[0]->version != $version && $json->data[0]->version > $version){
         echo 'Do Something'; 
    }
```

What do I have to do to not receive this notice?

Comment: This sounds like `$json` isn't an object. Try `var_dump($json);` and see what you get.

Comment: @ADyson Yes, sometimes it cannot receive json object. In such a case it shows this error.

Comment: P.S. Naming a variable $json when it's the result of `json_decode` is a bit nonsensical. json_decode turns a JSON string into a PHP variable. So its purpose is to get data _from_ JSON into something else. It doesn't output JSON - in fact, precisely the opposite :-)

Comment: `In such a case it shows this error`...well you'd better start checking the status of the variable before you try to use it then, so you don't get the error. `if ($json)` should be sufficient, since json_decode will return `null` if it fails.